# Why does Lance consider cell phones unsafe?

Tags: plot-explanation, pulp-fiction

In Pulp Fiction, drug dealer Lance is terrified when he understands that Vince is talking to him about drugs using a cell phone. He calls him a prank caller and hangs up.

He seems to think that cell phones may be wiretapped, but landline phones may not. Why?

Comment: Because the movie is from 1994, and back then analogue cellphones were more common than digital phones, and are not encrypted so are easy to listen into on scanners.

Comment: @iandotkelly jinx.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Cell phones at the time were unencrypted analog signals and could be picked up by any number of modified and unmodified radio systems. Scanner radios were easy to modify to pick them up. Even a UHF tv set could pick them up.

Current cell phones have moved to less easily accessible radio bands, encrypted, digital signals that jump from channel to channel, time divided, or frequencies. CDMA, TDMA, and FDMA, respectively. They can't be picked up with an off the shelf consumer radio.

A land line could definitely be wiretapped, but Lance likely knew his line wasn't, and the chance of an incoming line being tapped was low, and either would require a warrant and a large expenditure and good reasoning by police. But an analog cell phone wouldn't require a warrant. It's free air transmissions. ***Hell, look at current Stingray technology, where cops abuse the law and technology to wire tap cell phones without a warrant, on the basis that radio transmission isn't private.***

Comment: This was the center of  the pile of scandals that brought then-GOP Speaker Newt Ginrich down in the late 1990s.  A couple in Florida, using their police radio scanner intercepted John Boehner joining in a conference call with other GOP leadership to talk about their coordinated response to Ethics charges against Gingrich, to be announced later in the day.  Gingrich had a formal agreement with the Ethics committee for consideration in how they handled the case in exchange for him not coordinating PR/spin with his party. http://www.cnn.com/ALLPOLITICS/1997/01/13/tape/index.shtml

Comment: The couple got in trouble because that interception of the phone call and recording it was legally considered to be the same thing as an illegal wiretap of a phone.

Comment: Intercepting unencrypted cell phone conversations is also a major plot point in [*There's Something About Mary*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129387) in 1998

Comment: This was particularly annoying if you had a wireless home phone as you would frequently intercept callers, driving by, during your own phone conversations (and vice versa.)

Comment: @dugger.  That was a cordless phone but same concept.

Comment: [citation needed]. If the courts have ruled that the communication isn't private, then tapping it is not an abuse of the law. Conversely, by my understanding of the law, if the courts have ruled that the communication is private then cops need a warrant no matter the status of radio transmissions is.

Comment: @hurkyl laws change. But explain current day abuse of warrantless sting rays.

Comment: @cde: I don't know what you think needs explanation, because a citation is needed. :P  But I did a brief wikiwalk anyways, which suggests your (1) the wiretapping feature requires a warrant, and (2) it was other features, not wiretapping, for which it was argued a warrant wasn't required. (with the argument not "radio transmissions are public", but by comparison from what is and is not allowed with land lines)